# training one SVM model for predicting more than one response variable

Tags: machine-learning, r, algorithms

Please I want to know if there is any SVM R package that can handle more than one response variable (y) at a time. that is to train one model for predicting more than one response variable. it could be regression or multi class classification problem.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Just a little thought here. Why don't you just train one SVM for each response variable?

Comment: I second @PabloSuau's thought. Many packages have the capability to train multi-class classifiers, but often what's happening under the hood is that n binary classifiers are trained, and these are used individually to make predictions for each class. The SO question here also seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22009871/how-to-perform-multi-class-classification-using-svm-of-e1071-package-in-r

Answer (score 1):

e1071 is a highly popular and therefore safe solution for this purpose.

But if data starts to get bigger I would go with [classyfire](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/classyfire/classyfire.pdf). It's a quite fresh package built on e1071. It is highly optimized and have some other nice feature too. In my experience it produced similar results to e1071 but with a much faster speed as it was able to utilize all 4 core of my processor.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the e1071 package, here is the manual http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/e1071.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Clarification: are we talking about multiclass

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification

or multilabel?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification